# pytest: passing keyword arg to fixture using pytest.mark.parametrize with indirect parameterization

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I have a `pytest.fixture` that has one positional arg and one keyword arg.

Per [Pass a parameter to a fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function/33879151#33879151), one can pass args to a fixture using `pytest.mark.parametrize` with the `indirect` arg set to the fixture's name.

Please see the below sample code.

```py
import pytest

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: str):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

@pytest.fixture
def a() -> str:
    return "alphabet"

@pytest.fixture
def foo_obj(a: str, b: str = "bar") -> Foo:
    return Foo(a, b)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("foo_obj", [("applesauce", "baz")], indirect=["foo_obj"])
def test_thing(foo_obj) -> None:
    assert foo_obj.a == "applesauce"
    assert foo_obj.b == "baz"
```

This test fails currently: the `"applesauce"` and `"baz"` aren't getting passed into the fixture `foo_obj`.

My questions:

1. What am I doing wrong in passing the args to the fixture `foo_obj`?
2. Is it possible to only enter the kwarg `b` in the `pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator call?

   - Note: I am not interested in wrapping the fixture as suggested here: [Can I pass arguments to pytest fixtures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677426/can-i-pass-arguments-to-pytest-fixtures#44701916)

---

**Versions**

```
Python==3.8.5
pytest==6.0.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [answer from @MrBeanBremen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908379/pytest-passing-keyword-arg-to-fixture-using-pytest-mark-parametrize-with-indire#63908746) put me on the scent of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011902/pass-a-parameter-to-a-fixture-function#60148972), which talks about implicit indirect parametrization.

```py
@pytest.fixture
def foo_obj(a: str, b: str) -> Foo:  # Note: b was changed to positional arg
    print("hi")
    return Foo(a, b)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b", [("applesauce", "baz")])
def test_thing(foo_obj) -> None:
    assert foo_obj.a == "applesauce"
    assert foo_obj.b == "baz"
```

The tests pass in the above case.

It seems this implicit indirect parametrization can be used for positional args, but not for keyword args.  For example, if `b` was left as a keyword argument in the fixture `foo_obj`, pytest fails with the message: `In test_thing: function uses no argument 'b'`.

I am left wondering, is it possible to have keyword args be parameterized in this manner?

---

**Trying a 2nd time to use keyword arg**

I decided to make a new attempt again pulling on the [answer from @MrBeanBremen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908379/pytest-passing-keyword-arg-to-fixture-using-pytest-mark-parametrize-with-indire#63908746) and also this answer: [Provide default argument value for py.test fixture function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758406/provide-default-argument-value-for-py-test-fixture-function#47758594)

```py
@pytest.fixture
def a() -> str:
    return "alphabet"

@pytest.fixture
def foo_obj(request, a) -> Foo:
    return Foo(request.param.get("a", a), request.param.get("b", "bar"))

@pytest.mark.parametrize("foo_obj", [dict(a="applesauce", b="baz")], indirect=True)
def test_thing(foo_obj) -> None:
    # Override both defaults, passes
    assert foo_obj.a == "applesauce"
    assert foo_obj.b == "baz"

@pytest.mark.parametrize("foo_obj", [dict(b="baz")], indirect=True)
def test_thing_only_b(foo_obj) -> None:
    # Use the default for a
    assert foo_obj.a == "alphabet"
    assert foo_obj.b == "baz"
```

This works!  I feel as if it's a little convoluted with the `foo_obj` fixture accepting two args, when it sometimes uses one or the other.

Comment: Ah, nice! I think I have seen this before, but completely forgot about it - I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Okay check it now @MrBeanBremen.  Any ideas as to how I could clean up the 2nd part?

Comment: This looks very good to me - the way to use `dict.get` to have a default that behaves like a keyword arg is probably the best you can do. As for the 2 arguments (if you mean `request` and `a`) - they serve different purposes. The first is needed to get the paramatrized values, the second allows to customize one of the default values in a separate fixture, so as long as you to customize one default value (or both) , you need the additional fixture argument (or two...)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are mixing two things here: passing parameters to a fixture via `request.params`, and basing a fixture an another fixture (or fixtures).

To use the parameters used in `mark.parametrize` in your fixture, you have to take them from `request.params`, as shown in your linked question:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def foo_obj(request) -> Foo:
    return Foo(request.param[0], request.param[1])
```

What you are doing instead, is basing `foo_obj` on the fixture `a`, meaning, that `a` is the result of that fixture (e.g. it is always `"a"`), and a constant parameter `b`. Both have nothing to do with the values set by `parametrize` - these are set in `request.params` as shown above.

Comment: Ahhh yeah that's the problem, I missed the `.params`.  I am wondering, is `request` arg name a convention in `pytest`?

Comment: No, it is a keyword parameter (like the fixtures), which you have to use.

Comment: Ah, I see it documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=request#std-fixture-request).  Yes, I am new to `pytest`